# blackberry build using hudson signing automation not at configure page but inside the build

Tags: blackberry, hudson, sign

I know the automation of signature for blackberry app, as "java -jar ..signaturetool.jar....",
when I am building using hudson, i have to give at project config page by calling execute windows batch command ant task.
     But am writing a build which is common for different clients, that time i want to include 
this automation of signing within the build,as my app name will be changed according to the client's name and the path will be changed, so i want to execute this command line within the build, i tried this, but not working, its not executing the exec ant task.
  Can anyone help me where am missing, this is the code:

```
<property name="signpath" location="C:/Program Files/Research In Motion/BlackBerry JDE 5.0.0/bin/SignatureTool.jar"/>
<exec executable ="cmd" os="Windows XP" > 
 <arg line="java -jar ${signpath} -a -c -p pswd ${codfilepath}/${uid}/${uName}_${version}_${server}.cod"/>  
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following ANT target for signing. It requires the use of [bb_ant_tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) (which seems to be an industry standard, at least among stackoverflow users).

```
<target name="sign" depends="" 
    description="Signs the final COD file by calling the BlackBerry signing server. The password is stored in the common.properties file." >
    <sigtool
        codfile="${cod.output.dir}/${project.output}.cod" 
        jdehome="${sigtool.jde}" 
        password="${sigtool.password}" 
    />
</target>
```

All the parameters are stored in various properties files (I recommend keeping your signature password in a separate properties file to the rest of your project settings).

I would recommend this approach, since bb_ant_tools offers many useful features.

---

As to why the `exec` isn't working, I have had problems with `exec` when putting all parameters in one tag.

Try something like:

```
<exec executable="java" >
    <arg value="-jar" />
    <arg value="${signpath}" />
    <arg value="-a" />
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="-p" />
    <arg value="pswd " />
    <arg value="${codfilepath}/${uid}/${uName}_${version}_${server}.cod" />
</exec>
```

In my experience, each "space" character in the command line means you need to add a new `<arg value="...." />` line to the script. ymmv.

Comment: @user1330847 glad to help. Pls mark answer as accepted. For more info on Ant and BB, check my recent questions. I've just finished working on our build framework with lots of help from this community.